# RavenDB + Linqpad, I get Method not supported: GroupBy

Tags: ravendb, aggregate, linqpad

I try to run this query Inside Linqpad when connected to RavenDB:

```
from c in Query<Tournament.Models.Matches>() 
group c by c.Location into g
select g
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not understand expression: .GroupBy(c => c.Id).Select(g => g)
Method not supported: GroupBy

at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.GetLuceneQueryFor(Expression expression)
at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.Execute(Expression expression)
at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.Execute(Expression expression)
at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator()
at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

When run a simple query with no aggregation it runs ok.

I added references to Raven.Client.Lighweight and Raven.Abstaractions and still the same error

I'm probably missing something stupid.

Comment: Answered in the mailing list.

Comment: That answer is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/5rIznSoKyns/xyDyms-P2SUJ